Search over multiple indexes in elastic search matching specific fields if they exist
I'm trying to construct an elastic search query over multiple indexes using the elastic search dotnet client.
Given that I have three indexes with the property "name":

Area (name)
Municipalities (name)
Property (name, status)

If the field "status" is present in the document it must match "forSale" OR "upcomingSale", if status is not present, it should just ignore the "status" requirement
This is my query as it is today:
var indexes = new[] { "areas", "municipalities", "properties" };

var areaResponse = await _elasticsearchClient.SearchAsync<AreaSearchResult>(s => s
                .Indices(indexes)
                .Query(query =>
                    query.Prefix(prefix =>
                        prefix.Field(x => x.Name)
                            .CaseInsensitive()
                            .Value(q))), cancellationToken);

I cannot figure out a way where I can add the "exist" condition AND match the field status to specific values as a "must" in the query

So this is what I ended up with:
var areaResponse = await _elasticsearchClient.SearchAsync<AreaSearchResult>(s => s
            .Indices(indexes)
            .Query(query => query
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Filter(m => m
                            .Prefix(p => p.Field(x => x.Name)
                                .CaseInsensitive()
                                .Value(q)),
                        m => m
                            .Bool(b1 => b1
                                .Should(sh => sh
                                        .Bool(b2 => b2
                                            .Filter(mu => mu
                                                    .Term(t => t
                                                        .Field("_index")
                                                        .Value(_propertyIndex.IndexName)
                                                    ),
                                                mu => mu
                                                    .Terms(t => t
                                                        .Field(nameof(PropertyIndexModel.Status)
                                                            .LowercaseFirstLetter())
                                                        .Terms(new TermsQueryField(new[]
                                                        {
                                                            FieldValue.String(Status.ForSale.ToString()),
                                                            FieldValue.String(Status.UpcomingSale.ToString())
                                                        }))
                                                    )
                                            )
                                        ),
                                    sh => sh
                                        .Bool(b3 => b3
                                            .MustNot(mn => mn
                                                .Term(t => t
                                                    .Field("_index")
                                                    .Value(_propertyIndex.IndexName)
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                )
                            )
                    )
                )
            )

